# Selecting cases based on 2 variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I am sorry if it seems like a foolish question but I want to ask how to select cases that have the same id and index

This is an example of my dataframe:

```
df1<-structure(list(id = c(10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11), pnum = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 3), index = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Also  if in and index has the values across all pnums:

```
df2<-structure(list(id = c(10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11), pnum = c(1, 
    2, 3, 1, 2, 3), index = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L))
```

I need to select cases that have the same id and index

End table should be this:

for `df1`

```
  id     pnum   index
    11     1    1  
    11     2    1    
    11     3    1
```

Also when id and index belong to the same group:

```
df2 outcome

   id pnum  index
     10    1     2
     10    2     2
     10    3     2
```

Comment: Can you check the input example. it is not changed

Comment: Your second example expecetd and input is not the same

Comment: @akrun thanks yes I created a new example to show when index = 2 and id=10 are the same across the 3 pnum's

Comment: For the 'df2', I see the 'id' 10 have values 1 and 2 while id 11 have only 2.  Why the 'id' 10 is returned with 2

Comment: I am not sure about the logic in second case.  Updated the solution

Comment: Should the `id` be 11 in `df2` outcome? because id = 10 has 1 and 2 in `index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(df1, id == index)
#  id pnum index
#4  1    1     1
#5  1    2     1
#6  1    3     1
```

---

Or with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    filter(id == index)
```

---

For the second case, may be we can use

```
df2 %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter(n_distinct(index) > 1) %>% 
    mutate(index = 2)
```

Comment: @Rstudent your example is not clear.  What if there are only `pnum` with some values missing but the id and index are same i.e it didn't change.  Would you consider to keep those id or do you need the full set of pnum to be 1:3

Comment: @Rstudent Does the same condition holds i.e. a single value of 'index' to be filtered if there is only unique and 2 to be filtered in mixed?

Comment: @Rstudent In your updated example, it is the 'id' that takes 1 or 2.  Can you please check

Answer (score 0):

We can select `id`'s where there are only 1 unique `index` value.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[uniqueN(index) == 1], id]

#   id pnum index
#1: 11    1     1
#2: 11    2     1
#3: 11    3     1
```

For `df2` this returns as :

```
setDT(df2)[, .SD[uniqueN(index) == 1], id]

#   id pnum index
#1: 11    1     2
#2: 11    2     2
#3: 11    3     2
```

---

We can translate this to `dplyr` as :

```
df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(n_distinct(index) == 1)
```

and in base R :

```
subset(df1, ave(index, id, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 1)
```